# Find rows where one column string is in another column using dplyr in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, grepl

Looking to pull back rows where the value in one column exists as a string in another column (within the same row).

I have a df:

```
A <- c("cat", "dog", "boy")
B <- c("cat in the cradle", "meet the parents", "boy mmets world")

df <- as.data.frame(A, B)

A       B
cat     cat in the cradle
dog     meet the parents
boy     boy meets world
```

I'm trying things like:

```
df2 <- df %>%
          filter(grepl(A, B)) # doesn't work because it thinks A is the whole column vector

df2 <- df %>%
          filter(B %in% A) # which doesn't work because it has to be exact
```

I want it to produce

```
A       B
cat     cat in the cradle
boy     boy meets world
```

Thanks in advance!

Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either apply the function to both vectors using `Map` or iterate through the row using `sapply`

```
df %>%
  filter(unlist(Map(function(x, y) grepl(x, y), A, B)))
    A                 B
1 cat cat in the cradle
2 boy   boy mmets world

df %>%
  filter(sapply(1:nrow(.), function(i) grepl(A[i], B[i])))
    A                 B
1 cat cat in the cradle
2 boy   boy mmets world
```

Answer (score 6):

We can do this with `Map`

```
df[mapply(grepl, df$A, df$B),]
#    A                 B
#1 cat cat in the cradle
#3 boy   boy mmets world
```

#### Update

Using `tidyverse`, similar option would be `purrr::map2` with `stringr::str_detect`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   filter(map2_lgl(B, A,  str_detect))
#     A                 B
#1 cat cat in the cradle
#2 boy   boy mmets world
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(A, B, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, this can be easily done using `str_detect` from the dplyr tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(A, B) %>%
      filter(str_detect(B, fixed(A)) == TRUE)

df
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   A     B                
#  <chr> <chr>            
#1 cat   cat in the cradle
#2 boy   boy mmets world
```