# Create new column to show partial matches across strings in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a new column to show whether there is any match across strings in two columns in my dataframe. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874565/find-rows-where-one-column-string-is-in-another-column-using-dplyr-in-r) is almost what I'm asking, but rather than filtering, I want to create a new column to show whether there is a match or not (TRUE or FALSE).

So here is an example dataframe:

```
 transcript        target
 he saw the dog    saw
 she gave them it  gave
 watch out for     danger
 real bravery      brave
```

And I want to create a new column showing any match between the two:

```
 transcript        target    match
 he saw the dog    saw        T
 she gave them it  gave       T
 watch out for     danger     F
 real bravery      brave      T
```

I would prefer to use dplyr() but am open to other suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `stringr::str_detect` we can check if `transcript` contains `target`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%    #If transcript and target are character class  in your df then no need to this step
       mutate(match = str_detect(transcript,target))


         transcript target match
1   he saw the dog    saw  TRUE
2 she gave them it   gave  TRUE
3    watch out for danger FALSE
4     real bravery  brave  TRUE
```

Comment: Hi Suliman, how can I use str_detect to provide a value for the new column? Example : IF str_detect finds a word in an existing column, create a new column and mark that row as "found". Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AdilK, `str_detect` returns T/F hence we can use `ifelse` as usual, e.g. `df %>% mutate(newcol = ifelse(str_detect(transcript,target), "found", "not found"))`

Comment: Thanks, Suliman. I asked the question here and got an answer around using grep1, which works in my dataset. Is there a dplyr version of grep1 function? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505957/use-str-detect-function-to-conditionally-create-a-new-column-in-r-dataframe/61507415#61507415

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a dplyr method, but here is also a base R method using `grepl`:

```
df1$match <- mapply(grepl, df1$target, df1$transcript)

df1
        transcript target match
1   he saw the dog    saw  TRUE
2 she gave them it   gave  TRUE
3    watch out for danger FALSE
4     real bravery  brave  TRUE
```

using `grepl` inside a dplyr mutate statement:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(match = mapply(grepl, target, transcript))

        transcript target match
1   he saw the dog    saw  TRUE
2 she gave them it   gave  TRUE
3    watch out for danger FALSE
4     real bravery  brave  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

An option can be to use `dplyr::rowwise()` along with `grepl` to create the match column as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(match  = grepl(target,transcript)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#         transcript target match
# 1   he saw the dog    saw  TRUE
# 2 she gave them it   gave  TRUE
# 3    watch out for danger FALSE
# 4     real bravery  brave  TRUE
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"transcript        target
'he saw the dog'    saw
'she gave them it'  gave
'watch out for'     danger
'real bravery'      brave",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```