# Use str_detect function to conditionally create a new column in R dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with Column A containing values:

```
**Channel**
Direct
Paid social
Organic social
```

What I want to do: Create a new column called groupedChannel where str_detect searches for string in Column A to add a value in groupedChannel.

```
Condition:
IF row in Column A matches regex "direct" THEN Column B value = "Direct" ELSE
IF row in Column B matches regex "social" THEN Column B value = "Social"
```

AFAIK, str_detect will return only TRUE/FALSE. How can I use the TRUE/FALSE to assign a value in column B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using base R regex functions, also handles when direct and social are not found in Channel column

```
# Dummy data
data <- data.frame(Channel = c("Direct Paid", "Social", "Organic", "Social Organic"),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)

# Use sapply to iterate through each value in the 'Channel' column in the above dataframe
data$groupChannel <- sapply(data$Channel, FUN = function(x){
  # Use base R regex functions to for conditions, and return values for new column
  if (grepl("direct", tolower(x))){
    return("Direct")
  }else if (grepl("social", tolower(x))){
    return("Social")
  }else{
    return("Direct or Social Not Found")
  }
})

head(data)
  Channel               groupChannel
1    Direct Paid                     Direct
2         Social                     Social
3        Organic Direct or Social Not Found
4 Social Organic                     Social
```

Comment: Hi Jamie. Thanks, that worked. Is there a dplyr equivalent of grep1 function from base R?

Answer (score 1):

I have a `data.table` solution based on conditional replacement. It uses `grepl` but you could use `stringr::str_detect` if you want:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, groupedChannel := "Social"]

# Conditional replacement
df[grepl("direct",colA), groupedChannel := "Direct"]
```

(solution is untested)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to **match** your regex, not simply **detect**.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

tibble(
  colA = c("**Channel**", "Direct", "Paid social", "Organic social")
) %>% 
  mutate(
    colB = str_match(colA, "[Ss]ocial|[Dd]irect")[,1],
    colB = str_to_lower(colB)
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   colA           colB  
#>   <chr>          <chr> 
#> 1 **Channel**    <NA>  
#> 2 Direct         direct
#> 3 Paid social    social
#> 4 Organic social social
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

`stringr::str_match` returns a matrix, where the first column is the match itself, and subsequent columns for multiple groups, so we need to put `[,1]` at the end of that call. Then it matches both upper and lower case versions, so we convert all the matched groups to lowercase.

Alternatively, you could use `str_extract` like so: `colB = str_extract(colA, "[Ss]ocial|[Dd]irect"),` without the `[,1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `base R` solution, which assumes you have a clearly defined set of `Channel_group` values

Data:

```
data <- data.frame(Channel = c("Direct", "Paid social", "Organic social"),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
```

You can define your `Channel_group` values in a vector `a`:

```
a <- c("(S|s)ocial", "(D|d)irect")
```

Now you use `sub` to substitute the `Channel` values by the `Channel_group` values; `\\U` makes sure that these values are returned as upper-case strings (use `\\L` if you prefer to have lower-case strings):

```
data$Channel_group <- sub(paste0(".*\\b(", paste(a, collapse = "|"),")\\b.*"), "\\U\\1", data$Channel, perl = T)
```

Result:

```
data
         Channel Channel_group
1         Direct        DIRECT
2    Paid social        SOCIAL
3 Organic social        SOCIAL
```